Flutter ShareExtension for iOS: Flutter code executes but doesn't render UI
Flutter iOS Share Extension UI Not Rendering
I’m trying to create a Share Extension in Flutter for iOS, following the official Flutter guide: Creating App Extension UIs with Flutter.
Problem
While both Swift and Dart code appear to execute successfully (as confirmed by logs), the Flutter UI does not render. Instead, only the background view (green) is displayed, and the Flutter app content never shows up.
Here’s a minimal example repository I’ve created to reproduce the issue:
https://github.com/dagyu/ios_share_extension_flutter
Observations

GIF demonstration:
The green background view is displayed, but the Flutter content is missing. https://ibb.co/cbMTySH

Xcode logs:
Logs confirm that Dart and Swift code are executed as expected. https://ibb.co/Wkz1Nw2


Additional Information

Flutter version: 3.27.1 (tested with 3.24.0 and 3.22.0 as well).
Minimal reproducible example: https://github.com/dagyu/ios_share_extension_flutter


Any insights into why the Flutter UI isn’t rendering or how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you! 

Debugged multiple times to trace the issue, but the root cause of the missing Flutter UI remains unclear.
Tried with different Flutter versions (3.27.1, 3.24.0, and 3.22.0) to rule out version-related problems. The issue persists across all tested versions.

